# mysql syntax error on creating index

Tags: java, mysql

i have two mysql tables

tableA

```
col1   col2  SIM1 ..........col24
-----------------------------------
a       x     1             5 
b       y     1             3
c       z     0             2
d       g     2             1
```

tableB

```
colA   colB   SIM2
-------------------
x       g     1
y       f     0
x       s     0
y       e     2
```

i am using java to connect to mysql database using jdbc.

i need to index the two tables

```
   string query1 = " CREATE INDEX ON TableA (SIM1) ";
   string query2 = " CREATE INDEX ON TableB (SIM2) ";
```

when i use the excecuteUpdate(query1) and executeUpdate(query2) statements i get the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON TableA (SIM1)' at line 1
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is garbled. See the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

You query must include the index name:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON TableA (SIM1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you missed the index name: `CREATE INDEX IndexName ON ...`

For more details see the command reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html